# pixi.js lineTo drawing is shrinking when a distance between points becomes smaller

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm building line chart using the pixi.js lineTo method. The problem is the lines are shrinking when a distance between points becomes smaller. For testing purpose, I'm trying to draw 200,000 points on that chart.

Drawing function:

```
   var dataSet = ohlcStore[chartProperty.sym];

     if (dataSet && dataSet.length > 0) {
            var plot = new PIXI.Graphics();

            plot.setTransform(columnSize, (renderer.view.height - rowSize) + (Val_min * yScale), 1, -1 * yScale);

            plot.lineStyle(0.6, chartProperty.lineColor, 1);

            plot.moveTo(0, dataSet[0].close);

            for (i = 1; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
                try {
                    plot.lineTo(i * xScale, dataSet[i].close);
                } catch (x) {
                    console.error("Error - " + x);
                }
            }

            plot.endFill();

            context.addChild(plot);
        }
```

Result :

[image: Click to see result of lines drawing]

In this case, xScale is 0.006475032375161876 and Using the canvas render gives correct results.

Trying to search for the problem, I've found that the Pixi.js may have an issue with non-integer values. Therefore I've rounded values to integer but the problem didn't solve. Please support to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you add a picture of how you expect the chart to look?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/D9Q9RIu.jpg - I have uploaded the image. Please check.